# Cloned and Pushed a Forked Repo Successfully, Which Does NOT Read on Github

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Using git bash, Windows 10 64x.

Successfully forked a repo, and cloned it to mine.
Was able to read it on my computer.
Also, there was no technical issue in pushing the repo (to my repo, not as an upstream) - can't click on 'datasharing'[image].
But I cannot read it on GitHub, and can't figure out why.
Please help me.

Comment: Where did you fork it to? Are you sure your push goes to the same location you are trying to access in the github web ui? Github has had major service issues during the last ~20h, maybe you fell victim to that?

Comment: I just click 'fork' button and commanded to clone, and I think by then the file was available on my computer. Then I commanded to push it to my Github account repository. Then 'datasharing' appeared on my repo, where I was not able to get into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*datasharing* seems to be a submodule there. This means the original ower of the repo is using code from a foreign repo in his project. In order for you to use this code in a cloned repo you will have to obtain it separately after cloning your main repo. Imagine this like cloning a repo into a repo. This method is often used and perfect for referencing to external code while keeping all the advantages of version management rather than copying a static version of a library into your project.

Obtain the external code as follows:

1. Clone your repo as usual and cd into the folder.
2. `git submodule init`
3. `git submodule update`

The external code will be integrated into your repo and pushed/pulled with it. Not being able to click that folder seems to me as if github is aware of its existence but lacks the content.

For an exact reference on this topic you may want to read up on submodules in the docu found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).